# Database, "Pending status" design table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I have an already built project (which uses, Spring and JPA). One of the feature allows a user to add a place in the database (each place can be associated with a umber of tags, them also have to be approved by admin).

I would like to setup a "pending" state system, that when a user add a new place, this place is added to the database (postgreSQL in my case) 
but in a "pending state" and is not actually viewed as a final place. (then an admin will have to approve that place to make it visible to other user)

Is there any mechanism that Spring or JPA offers to archive this? 
Or is the only way is to redesign the table and modify all the queries ? (And if so, what would be a good design?, adding an extra column (state) ? or having separates tables etc.. ?

ps: so at the moment my design is as below:

table place:
id_place / name / etc...

table tag:
id_tag / name /etc..

table place_tag (that links every tag to its place)
id/id_place/id_taf
Thank you!

Comment: So you essentially want to add a row of data, and only make it active after admin validates it?

Comment: exactly, considering that my project is fairly big. What would be the best way to archive this? By having a new database design(this will imply having a big refactoring as all the existing queries will  be broken) Or have a duplicate table "pending_place, pending_tag and   pending_place_tag) ?

Comment: Neither, the way we do is have a extra column called "validated" which is a tinyint. When user submits info it stays as false, so they can view but its not active, when admin approves it becomes true and then data becomes active in application. That's simplest way to go about it. Happy to make it an official answer if you want

Comment: Yes this was also one of my approach, but is that the best approach (it sure it easy, but I'm looking here the best design). Also i have  completed my original question. Would this imply I will also have to add an extra column to my 2 other table?

Comment: Best to have minimal changes and most normalized as possible (the database design). It depends on how big the database is, how it runs all those factors. From what i have seen adding a single column to existing table with a tiny data set is best, as business logic of code and functional code need not major changes as well (so less chance of stuffing up in long run)

Comment: If you were working directly with the DB, rather than via JPA, you could use an updatable view for this.

Comment: @CraigRinger,  As Aeseir suggested, adding a new column seems a good idea. If I understood correctly the view would look something like this: CREATE VIEW place_view AS SELECT * from place where validated='Y'. I will then go through all my queries and change the "from" to make it used my place_view. Isn't using view supported with JPA entities?

Comment: @Johny19 Sure, you can use a view with JPA, the pain-point is that JPA doesn't make it easy to switch dynamically between a view and the underlying table. You can deal with that using fake inheritance relationships, multiple entities to map the same tables, or a few other tricks, but it might be easier to just use native queries when you want to manipulate the underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments and discussion most common and effective way i have seen this implemented and done is by including an extra column to existing tables e.g. "validated".

Some benefits include:

- minimal database changes
- effectiveness of queries doesn't drop
- business logic and functional code don't change drastically (coz you
  using existing methods etc.)

Again this will change based on opinion, experience, system complexity etc.

Hope it helps.